# Syntax error or access violation: 1148

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

На Laravel делаю загрузку CSV файла в базу данных через `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. Получаю ошибку `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`. Перерыл просто наверное весь Google и ответ везде один и тот же "Установите переменную `local-infile = 1` в `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`", я это естественно сделал, но ничего не меняется.

**Код:**

```
$query_load = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$import_file}' INTO TABLE {$table_name} FIELDS TERMINATED BY '".$this->column_delimiter."' ESCAPED BY '\"' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`name`,`url`,`desc`)";
$filling = DB::connection('temp')->getpdo()->exec($query_load);
```

**config/database.php:**

```
'temp' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_TEMP_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_TEMP_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_TEMP_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_TEMP_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_TEMP_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true]
]
```

Из-за чего может быть такая ошибка? Уже на протяжении 3 дней вожусь с этим и никакой информации кроме советов изменить `local-infile` не встречаю. Буду признателен за помощь!

**UPD:**

Вставляемое значение {$import_file} = `/data/www/site.com/assets/import/import.csv`
Столбцы которые вставляются: id, sku, main_category, sub_category, child_category, name, image, current_price, previous_price, description, condition, stock, variant, variant_quantity, variant_price, color, features, feature_colors, ship, youtube, meta_tag, meta_description, whole_sell_qty, whole_sell_discount, Товар Браслет, Товар Бренд, Товар Класс влагозащиты, Товар Диаметр, Товар Корпус, Товар Механизм, Товар Особенности, Товар Пол, Товар Страна регистрации бренда, Товар Стекло, Товар Стиль, Товар Функции.

P.s. то, что столбцы написаны по русски не приводит к этой ошибки 100%, уже проверенно.

Comment: Покажите вставляемое значение `'{$import_file}'`. А также значения всех глобальных переменных, связанных с импортом CSV/XML.

Comment: @Akina , добавил информацию в `UPD`,  смотрите.

Comment: Зачем биться головой об стену так долго? Неужели нельзя попробовать [альтернативные пути](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13454370/pdo-and-load-data-local-infile-not-working)?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov , если вы говорите про `fgetcsv()`, то собственно с этого пути мы и пришли к `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, на то есть свои причины.

Comment: *Вставляемое значение {$import_file} = `/data/www/site.com/assets/import/import.csv`* Вставляемый файл находится в локальной файловой системе. Удаляйте ключевое слово LOCAL - оно применяется только в случае импорта файла, находящегося на удалённом ресурсе. И я не вижу значений переменных - `secure_file_priv`, `tmpdir` и пр. да, не забудьте проверить наличие прав в файловой системе у учётки, под которой работает демон - может, он до этого файла тупо не достукивается...

Comment: @Akina , если убрать слово `LOCAL` , тогда мы получаем другую ошибку `SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied` . Это мы уже тоже пробовали делать. Насчет переменных которые вы написали, я не совсем понимаю, как их можно увидеть, чтоб я мог вам их показать.

Comment: *если убрать слово LOCAL , тогда мы получаем другую ошибку SQLSTATE[28000]: Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied* Вот теперь ошибка вменяемая. Проверяйте права в файловой системе. А заодно наличие привилегии FILE у MySQL-учётки. *я не совсем понимаю, как их можно увидеть* `SELECT @@имя_переменной;` (по одной) или `SHOW VARIABLES;` (все сразу).

Comment: @Akina , с переменными разобрался, `secure_file_priv = /var/lib/mysql-files/` , `tmpdir = /tmp`.

Comment: *`secure_file_priv = /var/lib/mysql-files/`* - LOAD DATA может загружать файлы ТОЛЬКО из этого каталога, без исключений. Внимательно изучите описание этой переменной.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112881/discussion-between-slam-and-akina).

Comment: Вопрос все ещё актуален.